# Merge two tables that don't share same primary key

Tags: mysql

I am trying to merge two tables that do no share the same primary key.
First table `foo`: CIP13 can be a primary key for table1, CodeCis cannot(duplicates).

```
|codeCis   |CIP13      |Price|
_______________________________________________
|12345677  |34009494960|5.96|
|12345678  |34009494977|12.25|
|12345678  |34009494978|32.25|
|12345679  |34009494979|15.95|
```

second table `goo`, for which CodeCis doesn't have dupplicates.

```
|codeCis   |MedicineName|
_______________________________________________
|12345677  |amoxicilline
|12345678  |clamoxyl|
|12345679  |valsartan|
```

I can have the desired output by this command :

```
select * from foo, goo where foo.codeCIS= goo.codeCIS;
```

But what I'd like is the create a new table that holds the result the previous line gave me.
Expected output :

```
|codeCis   |MedicineName | CIP13      |Price|
_______________________________________________
|12345677  |amoxicilline | 34009494960 | 5.96
|12345678  |clamoxyl     | 34009494977 | 12.25
|12345678  |clamoxyl     | 34009494978 | 32.25
|12345679  |valsartan    | 34009494979 | 15.95
```

That is, when codeCis from foo and goo match, i want the columns from foo and goo to appear for the said codeCis that matched. All codeCis will have a match, it's just that in foo table i can have several rows with the same codeCis.
Because both table don't share a same primary key i haven't been able to do it, any suggestion ?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Creating a table or view to contain the results of the join has nothing to do with primary keys.

Comment: @Utsav i added expected output

Comment: How did you choose `32.25` and not `12.25`?

Comment: @CristianTraìna CIP13 differs, one is a box of 30 tablets (12.25), other is a box of 90 tablets (32.25). Both have the same CIS because they belong to  the same medicine (Clamoxyl)

Comment: What you're trying to do is not a good practice in terms of database design. It looks like that your goo table is a lookup for codeCis. Why do you want to insert the same data that you can reach from two tables into a third table? You want to combine a lookup table and a table that already has the id of the related lookup.

Comment: @user you have edited your question :)

Comment: @CristianTraìna both different cip13 for prices were written in first table. But I thought it'd be clearer if i added both prices to the expected table to clear any confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TimBiegeleisen pointed out, primary keys have nothing to do with this requirement.

To get the result set you require, you want this, I believe. It's straightforward.

```
SELECT goo.codeCIS, goo.MedicineName, foo.CIP13, foo.Price
  FROM goo
  JOIN foo ON goo.codeCIS = foo.codeCIS
```

Don't create an actual table containing this sort of result set. If you need to give it a name call it a view.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW pricelist AS
SELECT goo.codeCIS, goo.MedicineName, foo.CIP13, foo.Price
  FROM goo
  JOIN foo ON goo.codeCIS = foo.codeCIS
```

Then you can do simpler queries such as

```
 SELECT * FROM pricelist WHERE MedicineName LIKE '%ox%'
```

to look things up.